# Report alignment getting distubred in other machine with same code

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I am working in a report which is generated through windows.print of javascript and content is passing to this function dynamically with the help of variables holding content of div tag.

While the layout and alignments are coming properly in one machine the same layout and alignment is getting disturbed in another machine though same code.

Default browser for my client is IE(11) and hence it should work in this browser in every machine.

What should I do to make it workable

EDIT :

```
function PrintActionDetails() {
    //window.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("divPrintActionDetails").innerHTML;
    //window.document.close();
    //window.focus();
    //window.print();
    //window.close();

    var objBlocks = new Array();
    //objBlocks[0] = "headerbox";
    objBlocks[0] = "divPrintActionDetails";
    Print(objBlocks, "&nbsp;");
    return true;
}

    function Print(blocks, strHeading) {
        var prtContent = "<table border='0' width='100%'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td align='center'>" + strHeading + "<p></td></tr><tr><td style='border:none'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            prtContent += document.getElementById(blocks[i]).innerHTML;
            prtContent += "</td></tr>";

            if (i < blocks.length - 1)
                prtContent += "<td style='border:none'><tr>";

        }

        prtContent += "</table>";

        var my_window = window.open("", "mywindow1", "status=1,width=550,height=300,scrollbars=yes");
        //var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=2000,top=2000,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=1');
        //var htmlhead = '<html><head><link href="http://localhost:51430/Css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="http://localhost:51430/Css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" /></head><body>';
        var htmlhead = '<html><head><link href="http://localhost:51430/Css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="http://localhost:51430/Css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>';
        var htmlfooter = '</body></html>';
        var WinPrintInnerHTML = htmlhead + prtContent + htmlfooter;
        // my_window.document.open();
        my_window.document.body.innerHTML = WinPrintInnerHTML;
        my_window.document.close();
        my_window.focus();
        my_window.print();
        my_window.close();
    }

Styles.CSS:- @media print {
*, *:before, *:after { color:#000 !important; text-shadow:none !important; background:transparent !important; -webkit-box-shadow:none !important; box-shadow:none !important}
a, a:visited { text-decoration:underline; }
a[href]:after { content:" (" attr(href) ")"; }
abbr[title]:after { content:" (" attr(title) ")"; }
a[href^="#"]:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after { content:""; }
pre, blockquote { border:1px solid #999; page-break-inside:avoid; }
thead { display:table-header-group; }
tr, img { page-break-inside:avoid; }
img { max-width:100% !important; height:auto; }
p, h2, h3 { orphans:3; widows:3; }
h2, h3 { page-break-after:avoid; }
select { background:#fff !important; }
.navbar { display:none; }
.btn > .caret, .dropup > .btn > .caret { border-top-color:#000 !important; }
table { border-spacing:0!important; border-collapse:collapse!important; }
table { background-color:transparent!important; }
.label { border:0px solid transparent!important; }
.table { border-collapse:collapse !important;page-break-after:always!important;width:98%}
.table td, .table th { background-color:#fff !important; }
table.table-bordered{border: solid #ddd !important; border-width: 0 1px 1px 0 !important; margin:10px 0 10px 0!important; border-width:1px !important; }
table.table-bordered th, .table-bordered td { border:1px solid #ddd !important; border-width:1px !important;}
table .table-bordered th { border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important; }
table .table-bordered tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd !important; }
/*.table .thead-one tr th:last-child { border-bottom:0px solid #ddd !important}*/

/* * {overflow: hidden;}*/
th, td { border:solid #ddd !important; border-width:0 1px 1px 0 !important; border-width:1px !important; }
.contenttable {width:99%!important;}
.contenttable98 {width:98%!important;}
.contenttable90 {width:90%!important;}
.prn-no-bdr, th.prn-no-bdr, td.prn-no-bdr, tr.prn-no-bdr th {border:none !important;line-height:18px!important}
.prn-bdr {border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd !important}
.bg-white{background:#fff !important;}
body { font-family:Calibri, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:14px; /*line-height:1.42857143;*/ color:#524e4e; background:none!important;background-image:none!important }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show the code of the print page, including the css. We can't tell you anything about which css code looks different in different browsers if we don't know the css.

Comment: @Silly : CSS is quite long and can't accepted in the body of question. Is there any provision in stack overflow to send the file as attachment

Comment: Make a plunkr, jfiddle, or just cut out the relevant parts.

Comment: As per your suggesation added part of the css which is applicable with the javascript function which is getting called on print button click..